# Where to change route '/home' when user is login and try to login again in laravel

Tags: laravel

I just want to know where are the Auth routes defined.
In my case I am logged In but for testing purpose try to go to login page agian using

```
localhost/login
```

this should take me to my dashboard or profile but it redirects to '/home' and unable to found this view.
How to configure this route and where to configure this in laravel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `RedirectIfAuthenticated` in the `App\Http\Middleware` folder:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

So change the `redirect('/home');` to where ever you want it to redirect.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Khalid Dabjan it works like I was wanting.

Answer (score 1):

The code that defines the route to redirect after a successful login.

```
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

The code that redirects a logged in user if they try to visit a `guest` page.

```
app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

return redirect('/home');
```

The code that redirects a user to the login page when an unauthenticated user tries to open a page that needs authentication.

```
app/Exceptions/Handler.php

return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

Comment: Thanks @sandeesh for your answer. It acknowledge me where to manipulate auth routes

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 6 and above.
Just go to app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
and change

```
public const HOME = '/home'
```

to

```
public const HOME = '/new-name'
```